# Read set of images into 4D Numpy array with dimension (num_img,channel, dim1, dim2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of 1000 gray scale images (28x28), I want to read them into 4D numpy array (number of images, 1, img_dim1,img_dim2). Following is my code but it doesn't work properly. Any idea how I can fix the issue in the code?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

mypath=os.path.dirname('path/to/directory/')
def load_dataset( ) :
    data =np.zeros((1000,1,28,28), dtype=np.float64)
    for fname in os.listdir(mypath):
        pathname = os.path.join(mypath, fname)
        img = Image.open(pathname)
        data = np.dstack((data, img))
    return data
data=load_dataset()
print(data.shape)
```

Comment: What is it that's not working? Please tell us the issue or what error you're getting.

Comment: Why the extra dimension? You could `enumerate` your paths and insert into `data[i] = img`, since data is already pre-allocated. With dstack, you are basically asking it to append `omg` to the end of `data`, which is already allocated at the right size, rather than inserting. Not clear on the use of `return` outside a function, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by using `append` and adding a new axis `np.newaxis`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

mypath=os.path.dirname('path/to/directory/')
def load_dataset( ) :
    data =[]
    for fname in os.listdir(mypath):
        pathname = os.path.join(mypath, fname)
        img = Image.open(pathname)
        img1 = img[np.newaxis,:,:]
        data.append(img1)
    return data

data= load_dataset()
data_x=np.array(data)
print data_x.shape
```

Comment: How this fixed your problem? I got 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable' on the line 'img = Image.open(pathname)'